# How to display different content on a modal based on data-binding attribute? (knockout.js + bootstrap modal)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is, I want to display a modal when I click the "Preview Application" link based on the data-binding of the link.

For example,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }">

   Preview Application

</a>
```

When I do this, it binds to the corresponding applicationKey. So, I want to use this information to display the corresponding candidateLocation on the modal based on the applicationKey.

How can I do this?

To rephrase my question,

How can I make the modal read the applicationKey and display the candidateLocation that is inside the same "application" object as that applicationKey?

The code for my empty modal currently looks like this:

```
<div id="previewApplicantModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Applicant Preview</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span>Applicant Responses</span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row small-margin-top" style="text-align:center">
                <a href="#">Read Full Profile</a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about knockstrap modal   https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#modal

Comment: @BryanDellinger I am trying to display another element (location) in the object based on the specific element (applicantKey) in the same object. Is this possible by doing that?